# Can't run sgolayfilt () on RasterStackTS in R

Tags: r, modis

I'm quite new in R and remote sensing at all. Had followed the following step to filter my MODIS/NDVI data.

```
library(sp)

library(raster)

library(rgdal)

library(rts)

library(signal)

getwd()

setwd('D:/NDVI')

list.files()

ndvils <- list.files(pattern='.img$',full.names=TRUE) #file list uusgeh

ndvistk<- stack(ndvils) #stack hiih

d <- c("2001-01-01","2001-01-17","2001-02-02","2001-02-18","2001-03-06","2001-03-22","2001-04-07","2001-04-23","2001-05-09","2001-05-25","2001-06-10","2001-06-26","2001-07-12","2001-07-28","2001-08-13","2001-08-29","2001-09-14","2001-09-30","2001-10-16","2001-11-01","2001-11-17","2001-12-03","2001-12-19","2002-01-01","2002-01-17","2002-02-02","2002-02-18","2002-03-06","2002-03-22","2002-04-07","2002-04-23","2002-05-09","2002-05-25","2002-06-10","2002-06-26","2002-07-12","2002-07-28","2002-08-13","2002-08-29","2002-09-14","2002-09-30","2002-10-16","2002-11-01","2002-11-17","2002-12-03","2002-12-19","2003-01-01","2003-01-17","2003-02-02","2003-02-18","2003-03-06","2003-03-22","2003-04-07","2003-04-23","2003-05-09","2003-05-25","2003-06-10","2003-06-26","2003-07-12","2003-07-28","2003-08-13","2003-08-29","2003-09-14","2003-09-30","2003-10-16","2003-11-01","2003-11-17","2003-12-03","2003-12-19","2004-01-01","2004-01-17","2004-02-02","2004-02-18","2004-03-05","2004-03-21","2004-04-06","2004-04-22","2004-05-08","2004-05-24","2004-06-09","2004-06-25","2004-07-11","2004-07-27","2004-08-12","2004-08-28","2004-09-13","2004-09-29","2004-10-15","2004-10-31","2004-11-16","2004-12-03","2004-12-18","2005-01-01","2005-01-17","2005-02-02","2005-02-18","2005-03-06","2005-03-22","2005-04-07","2005-04-23","2005-05-09","2005-05-25","2005-06-10","2005-06-26","2005-07-12","2005-07-28","2005-08-13","2005-08-29","2005-09-14","2005-09-30","2005-10-16","2005-11-01","2005-11-17","2005-12-03","2005-12-19","2006-01-01","2006-01-17","2006-02-02","2006-02-18","2006-03-06","2006-03-22","2006-04-07","2006-04-23","2006-05-09","2006-05-25","2006-06-10","2006-06-26","2006-07-12","2006-07-28","2006-08-13","2006-08-29","2006-09-14","2006-09-30","2006-10-16","2006-11-01","2006-11-17","2006-12-03","2006-12-19","2007-01-01","2007-01-17","2007-02-02","2007-02-18","2007-03-06","2007-03-22","2007-04-07","2007-04-23","2007-05-09","2007-05-25","2007-06-10","2007-06-26","2007-07-12","2007-07-28","2007-08-13","2007-08-29","2007-09-14","2007-09-30","2007-10-16","2007-11-01","2007-11-17","2007-12-03","2007-12-19","2008-01-01","2008-01-17","2008-02-02","2008-02-18","2008-03-05","2008-03-21","2008-04-06","2008-04-22","2008-05-08","2008-05-24","2008-06-09","2008-06-25","2008-07-11","2008-07-27","2008-08-12","2008-08-28","2008-09-13","2008-09-29","2008-10-15","2008-10-31","2008-11-16","2008-12-03","2008-12-18","2009-01-01","2009-01-17","2009-02-02","2009-02-18","2009-03-06","2009-03-22","2009-04-07","2009-04-23","2009-05-09","2009-05-25","2009-06-10","2009-06-26","2009-07-12","2009-07-28","2009-08-13","2009-08-29","2009-09-14","2009-09-30","2009-10-16","2009-11-01","2009-11-17","2009-12-03","2010-01-01","2010-01-17","2010-02-02","2010-02-18","2010-03-06","2010-03-22","2010-04-07","2010-04-23","2010-05-09","2010-05-25","2010-06-10","2010-06-26","2010-07-12","2010-07-28","2010-08-13","2010-08-29","2010-09-14","2010-09-30","2010-10-16","2010-11-01","2010-11-17","2010-12-03","2010-12-19","2010-12-19","2011-01-01","2011-01-17","2011-02-02","2011-02-18","2011-03-06","2011-03-22","2011-04-07","2011-04-23","2011-05-09","2011-05-25","2011-06-10","2011-06-26","2011-07-12","2011-07-28","2011-08-13","2011-08-29","2011-09-14","2011-09-30","2011-10-16","2011-11-01","2011-11-17","2011-12-03","2011-12-19")

date <- as.Date(d, format = "%Y-%m-%d") #on,sar,udur format bolgoh

date 

class(date)

ndvi<-rts(ndvistk,date)>

ndvifilt<-sgolayfilt(ndvi, p=1, n=3, ts=30)
```

Receiving error:

```
Error in stats::filter(c(init.x, x), filt/a[1], sides = 1) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'
```

Please help with the steps and suggest me how I can write my filtered data in separate geoTIFF files.

Comment: `ndvi` is a `RasterStackTS` object, i.e. a Raster* object with time attributes. `sgolayfilt` needs a vector and doesn't know how to deal with that.